# tf_listener error transform.tf::Transform::getOrigin does not have class type

Tags: ros, tf-listener, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I used the "Writing a tf listener (C++)" tutorial and Publishing Sensor Streams Over ROS tutorial and I created a sensor_msgs/pointcloud msg after listening to tfs... and the  my code is shown bellow:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
//#include <turtlesim/Velocity.h>
 #include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h> 
 #include <turtlesim/Spawn.h>
 #include "sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h"
 #include "tf/message_filter.h"
#include "laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
 ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf_listener");
 ros::NodeHandle node;
 //ros::service::waitForService("spawn");// ##
 //ros::ServiceClient add_turtle = node.serviceClient<turtlesim::Spawn>("spawn"); //##
 //turtlesim::Spawn srv; // ##
 //add_turtle.call(srv); // ##
 ros::Publisher cloud_pub = node.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud>("cloud", 50);
 unsigned int num_points = 100;
 tf::TransformListener listener;
  int count = 0;
  ros::Rate rate(10.0);
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;
  while (node.ok()){
   tf::StampedTransform transform;
try{
  listener.lookupTransform("/obstacle/right_up_corner", "/base_link",ros::Time(0), transform);
  
  cloud.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  cloud.header.frame_id = "sensor_frame";
  cloud.points.resize(num_points);
  //we'll also add an intensity channel to the cloud
  cloud.channels.resize(1);
  cloud.channels[0].name = "intensities";
  cloud.channels[0].values.resize(num_points);
  //cloud.points.x = transform.getOrigin.x();
  //cloud.points.y = transform.getOrigin.y();
  //cloud.points.z = transform.getOrigin.z();
  // generate some fake data for our point cloud
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i){
   cloud.points[i].x =transform.getOrigin.x();// 1 + count;
   cloud.points[i].y =transform.getOrigin.y();// 2 + count;
   cloud.points[i].z =transform.getOrigin.z();// 3 + count;
   cloud.channels[0].values[i] = 100 + count;//#
   }

  cloud_pub.publish(cloud);

   ++count;


}
catch (tf::TransformException ex){
  ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
}

rate.sleep();
 }
  return 0;
};
```

I got the following error

transform.tf::Transform::getOrigin’ does not have class type

What is the error in this code ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152611/tf_listener-error-transform.tf::transform::getorigin-does-not-have-class-type/) by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[getOrigin()](http://ftp.isr.ist.utl.pt/pub/roswiki/doc/unstable/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html#a55a6538f2d7762a05e5b96bc7d02562d) is a function of the tf::Transform class and as such has to be called with trailing `()`, indicating it is a function with 0 arguments.

You should really try searching for this kind of compile errors, as those are typical novice C++ mistakes that happened to many people before. Googling "does not have class type" gives you the correct answer pretty quickly.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on 2014-04-14**:
Thank you it worked